# How to fill NaN for categorical data randomly?

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have a table like this one:

| Sex | SchGend |
| --- | --- |
| M | Boys |
| F | Girls |
| NaN | Mixed |
| NaN | Boys |

And I want to fill the NaNs values within this table (there are 100 hundred of them). The SchGend tells if the school is only for boys, only for girls or for both. Thus, to fill the 4th row I want to put M as the sex, but to fill the NaN for the mixed school I want to do it with random value. I have no idea on how to put a condition in the fillna method for pandas.

So that is my question: how can I do that? Any tips?

Comment: This a _much_ more focused question than your last one. Thank you for the reduction in scope, it really makes questions more answerable within Stack Overflow guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, fill the values for known values from the school information. Then fill the remaining randomly.
You can use `random.choices` to generate a random sequence of "M" and "F" (There should be alternative functions in `numpy.random` if you prefer).

If you run the below, you will get different outcomes for the third record.

```py
from io import StringIO
import random
import pandas as pd

data = """
Sex SchGend
M   Boys
F   Girls
NaN Mixed
NaN Boys
"""

x = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep="\t")

# fill cases of boys or girls school
x.loc[x.SchGend == "Boys", "Sex"] = "M"
x.loc[x.SchGend == "Girls", "Sex"] = "F"

num_na = x.Sex.isna().sum()  # number of missing cases
x.loc[x.Sex.isna(), "Sex"] = random.choices(["M", "F"], k=num_na)
x
```

Comment: I was trying to use the series.map method, it was doing pretty well but I could not handle the cases where the choice needed to be random inside a dictionary lol . Your answer worked just fine. Thanks for your time, helped a lot.

Comment: Solid Answer +1. It may be a better approach to calculate `m = x.Sex.isna()` then do `x.loc[m, "Sex"] = random.choices(["M", "F"], k=m.sum())` because currently you're finding the `NaN` twice which can be slow on large datasets.